# Android UI Thread overloaded - handling large uploads/downloads

Tags: android, multithreading, file-upload, android-asynctask

I have an android application that is failing intermittently. I have evidence this is happening when there is a large upload occurring where I use an AsyncTask to upload the files via HTTP. My most recent reading of the docs concerning the AsyncTask leads me to believe that I'm using the wrong mechanism.

It looks like the proper mechanism is to use some kind of background service, so the upload won't get shut down the way it can under an AsyncTask. The docs on [Background Operations](https://developer.android.com/guide/background/index.html) suggest that maybe I should use a JobService. That looks like it would make sure my job gets restarted if killed, but I'm not sure if that alone will fix this problem, because the upload might still be large enough that the job will be killed over and over.

So it looks to me like I have a couple options, but don't know which ones are most likely to help:

- Break the big upload into a bunch of scheduled jobs that are small
  enough I don't have to worry they'll never upload.
- Find a way to significantly shrink the upload. (Might be possible since it is
  mostly pictures and I might be able to compress them more.)
- Put the upload in a background thread and make sure the application stays
  active until the upload is finished.
- Something I haven't thought of.

I would like to hear what more experienced developers than I have to say. If you've done something like this, what did you do?

Again, thanks for taking the time to read this question and help me.

Ray

Comment: Standard disclaimer that asking for off-site resources/tutorials is off-topic. A few things to think about: Are the uploads atomic (i.e. do all of the files need to be at the server to be successful)? Realize that not everyone has 4G network so recovery from bad connection (tunnel, subway, slow/bad network) is always preferred.

Comment: Yes, all of the uploaded files need to be at the server for the upload to be successful. 
Thanks for warning on asking for off-site stuff. I'll remove that.
There is some recovery already built-in. If an order isn't successfully transmitted, it is retried. The problem is that the uploads keep failing. We have a backup manual method, but that's less than optimal.

Comment: Figure out why the upload is failing. Server configuration problem? Too big? Works in lab but not in field, find out what are the client conditions. If you can work with your server team to be able to stitch together multiple uploads/downloads (tied together via UUID for example) it will give you the most options, including if you need to do image quality reduction.